# How to get today, tomorrow and next week date using Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to show `today`, `tomorrow` and `nexweek` date like (27th Aug, 2019) formate. Here, I can able to get today and tomorrow date but can't able to get nextweek.

```
extension Date {
    static var daytomorrow: Date { return Date().tomorrow }
    static var daynextweek:  Date { return Date().nextweek }
    var tomorrow: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!
    }
    var nextweek: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: noon)!
    }
    var noon: Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)!
    }
}
```

By calling this

```
print("\(Date())")
print("\(Date.daytomorrow)")
print("\(Date.daynextweek)")
```

How to get next week date with this (27th Aug, 2019) formate.

Comment: Use Date and not NSDate and look up the documentation for Date for an answer to your question

Comment: You should never use String interpolation for presenting dates for users. Most users don't use the same date format. You should use `DateFormatter` for locale-aware date formatting.

Comment: Do not completely change your question in a way that makes current comments and answers irrelevant. Either add information by editing your question or ask a completely new question

Answer (score 3):

```
date.addDays(.day, 1)! // Tomorrow  
date.addDays(.day, 7)! // Next Week
```

---

```
func addDays(_ unit: Calendar.Component, NumOfDays: Int) -> Date? {
            return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: unit, value: NumOfDays, to: self)
        }
```

Comment: great. what about today? @Ramprasath Selvam

Comment: @BenDev I hope you can look into the documentation for that. If you read the documentation you will find most of the solutions.

Comment: I updated my question, Sorry @ Ramprasath Selvam